# Transfer open workbook from one Excel instance to another

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to transfer an open workbook to another Excel instance? I.e. 're-parenting' an open workbook without closing and re-opening?

The reason I want to do this is to have a separate instance for a particular workbook. When that workbook opens, it can create a new instance of Excel, and then I'm hoping to somehow add that workbook to the other applications Workbooks collection, while removing it from the original.

The point of this is so that I can run a modal forms application, while still retaining the ability to use Excel. For example, I'd like to programatically copy data to the clipboard while letting the user paste it into another workbook.

Making the original forms application non-modal is NOT a solution as this is a requirement (we've gone to elaborate lengths to keep regular users out of the worksheets and only close the forms with a password.)

For context, I've tried opening the other instance with the same workbook and then closing, but this has problems with the newly opened workbook being read-only. (There are also other reasons why this doesn't work well.)

Answer (score 0):

As the code below demonstrates, you can access a workbook in another instance of Excel and manipulate it.

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim xlApp2 As Excel.Application
Dim Wb2 As Workbook

Set Wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set xlApp = Wb.Parent

Set xlApp2 = New Excel.Application
Set Wb2 = xlApp2.Workbooks.Open("E:\My Documents\Weekly Report.xlsx")

Wb.Worksheets("Target").Cells(1, 1).Value = Wb2.Worksheets(1).Cells(4, 1).Value
```